# My program not iterating properly

Tags: python, loops

I am writing a simple program and My for loop is off a bit. It only reads the last entry. I know it is only outputting the last entry and I know why, but I cant seem to fix it.
Any help would be great. I can get it to run another way, but I want to use the loop.

```
def main(): 



    testfile = open('tests.txt', 'w')

    #### THIS RUNS -- but only output is last entry #####

    for count in range(1, 6):
        test = int(input('Enter the test score: #' + \
                          str(count) + ' % '))




    testfile.write(str(test) + '\n')



    testfile.close()
    print('The scores are in the tests.txt file.')

main()
```

The output into a text file.

```
>>> 
Enter the test score: #1 % 89
Enter the test score: #2 % 98
Enter the test score: #3 % 69
Enter the test score: #4 % 36
Enter the test score: #5 % 36
The scores are in the tests.txt file.
>>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python cares about indentation: the only thing inside of your loop is the `input` statement, so your `write` only happens once: after the last value has been entered.

You need to indent the `write` statement the same as the `input` one to put it inside the loop.

Comment: Very nice! Thank you!